# Form Sign up Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: php, html

Huge Campaign form email suddenly stops working, not entirely sure what the issue is here. It goes to a service unavailable page?

It was working a couple of days ago.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['cd_FULLNAME'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['Email'];
$dropdown = $_POST['dropdown'];
$message = $_POST['cd_CONTACTPHONENUM'];


$email_from = 'websmail@wscu.com';//<== update the email addresss
$email_subject = "RRSP Campaign Phone Call Request";
$email_body = "The following information was submitted via our external landing page wscu.com/savings. The prospective customer has been informed that they will be contacted by a representative within 1 business day regarding our RRSP Campaign. \n Their name is: $name.\n".

$to = "wscumemberservicecentre@wscu.com, ecommerce@wscu.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thankyou.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="lowerForm" id="lowerForm" action="form-to-email.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_lowerForm(this)" autocomplete="on">
```

Comment: "service unavailable page"? sounds like an issu with your host

Comment: Why is that `IsInjected()` function there, if it is not used? Also, the test whether something is submitted doesn't work, it will fall through that and go to the thank you page, if it works again.

Comment: I had similar problem. Turned out my host had updated some apache security settings and only published php files with the correct permissions. Any "rw-rw-rw" files gave a 500 error.